# APFS partition error

Tags: bootcamp, high-sierra, partition, apfs

So I've searched for a while and found several answers but I don't want to take a chance with the wrong command and wipe data so I'd like instructions specific to my case please.

I resized my Windows7 partition with GParted which left 12Gb free. I then used a command in Terminal to reclaim that space in the APFS Container, operation was successful but then the volume briefly appeared under "External" ... I rebooted and now its gone.

Current state :
[image]

disk0s2 is the High Sierra volume, is it possible to reactivate that partition without losing the Windows one ?

UPDATE : So klanomath fixed the problem with the APFS partition but the Windows one while visible remains "unbootable". I ran a Windows RE a few times which fixed things supposedly (last pass it said everything was fine) but when I press Alt at startup the partition isn't showing. When I select the volume from the Startup panel in System Preferences it just reboots to a black screen (no error just prompt)...

New state :

[image]

Comment: Im currently booted from an external SSD with High Sierra. I don't have another Mac.

Comment: Oh that's fine. If you install TeamViewer and invite me to a session we will fix your problem (hopefully). The answer is probably a mixture of this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305706/os-volume-shows-as-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff and this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306204/apfs-partition-disappeared-after-creating-hybrid-mbr

Comment: I was about to run sudo gdisk /dev/disk0 but I have TeamViewer ready, should I post my ID and Password here ? edited - OK won't use it

Comment: @ankii Which purposes do you mean? Telling my email someone else instead of posting it in a comment here?

Comment: @ankii The preset of TeamViewer is a new random 6x lowercase a-z & digits "password" everytime it is launched. In yesterday's (in fact: today's) session (from ~1am - ~4am GMT+2) we had to reboot the OP's Mac 4 times. I don't think Google Forms helps here. ;-)

Comment: @Feflechi I would split the question: 1. the original one (which is a duplicate of another - I have to search for the perfect match to raise this flag) and a second (new) one which deals with the non-booting Win7. The second one may also have an answer already but we haven't found it yet. A good start is D. Anderson's [answer list](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/107222/david-anderson?tab=answers&sort=newest&page=1). Adding an update to a question with a more or less new objective is not appreciated here.